# Custom sorting with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

It seems that i'm missing something trivial.

Anyway, here it goes:

```
var order = new[]{1,3,2};
var foos = new[]{new Foo{Id=1}, new Foo{Id=2}, new Foo{Id=3}};
```

How to sort foos by order array using Linq?

Desired result:

```
foos == new[]{new Foo{Id=1}, new Foo{Id=3}, new Foo{Id=2}};
```

**Edit:**
Order contains Foo ids. Sorry that i didn't mention that. Sometimes it's even harder to ask question properly than to answer it. :)

Comment: Does the `order` array specify the array indices or `Id`s of `Foo`s?

Comment: Indeed - please clarify the question. I've put an explanation of what I *think* you're asking for in the my answer, but I'm just guessing. (For example, Dale Halliwell has guessed at a different meaning.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the question doesn't seem to be *entirely* clear to me, so I'll try to clarify what I *think* you're asking:

- You have a sequence of IDs, in the desired order
- You have a collection of objects, *not* in the right order, but with corresponding IDs
- You want to get the collection of objects in the same order as the ID sequence

Correct?

That would be:

```
var orderedFoos = from orderedId in order
                  join foo in foos on orderedId equals foo.Id into groups
                  select groups.Single();
```

You need a `join ... into` to verify that you don't have any missing or duplicate IDs in `foos`. It won't, however, detect if you've got missing or duplicate IDs in `order`. If you know that everything will be correct (i.e. there will be exactly one entry in `foos` for every entry in `order` and vice versa) then a simple join is okay:

```
var orderedFoos = from orderedId in order
                  join foo in foos on orderedId equals foo.Id
                  select foo;
```

which can be expressed in dot notation as:

```
var orderedFoos = order.Join(foos, order => order, foo => foo.ID, (o, f) => f);
```

Comment: I don't think this resolves the problem. I think the OP basically wants to grab `Foo`s that have the specific **Id** in a specific position.

Comment: Sorry Skeet, can't use .NET 4.0

Comment: @Arnis: That's why I linked to MoreLINQ - but I'd misunderstood the problem.

Comment: (I've now rewritten the answer using a GroupJoin.)

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
foos.OrderBy(f => order[f.Id-1]);
```

If you foreach now on the output of that, printing the ID, you get: 1,3,2

Comment: Some of these answers based on joins will be a lot more expensive over large sets that this little LINQ using a comparator.

Comment: I think your answer is doing a different thing to all the other answers. It's also *more* expensive than the joins, which should be O(n) - your answer is O(n log n).

Comment: In terms of the differences of answer... you're assuming that `foos` is already in order, and will have ID 1, 2, 3, 4... with no gaps.

Comment: Really?? Order should use quicksort or something better, so yes, O(n log n), but intuition tells me a join (an equijoin, in the case of LINQ) has to be around O(n^2).. where did you get O(n) from?

Comment: Yes it is making a few assumptions, the OP needs clarification

Comment: @Dale: It will create a hash on the "inner" part then use that to match. Assuming we have a 1-1 correspondence (i.e. we don't have N entries all with the same key) and the hash is reasonable (i.e. lookup is O(1), creation is O(1) per item) then the result is O(N).

Comment: There can be gaps and will be for sure (my bad - forgot to add this in question). But thanks for idea anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
from o in order.Select((o, i) => new { o, i })
join f in foos on o.o equals f.Id
orderby o.i
select f;
```

Comment: Why are you ordering by `o.i`? It will already be in that order.

Comment: To elaborate: If I don't order, I have to know which of the sequences (if any) is order-preserved. It might be well defined for this operator in LINQ to objects, but if it were LINQ to SQL, it wouldn't be. Also, if I misread the documentation, I could introduce a hard-to-find bug by omitting the orderby (if I only tested it with 3 items, I assume a 1/6 chance of accidentally passing since I don't know the implementation details). By adding the orderby I get rid of these problems without hurting anyone.

Comment: erikkallen: "...without hurting anyone." Except performance implication of performing an unnecessary sort.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use a `Dictionary<int,int>` of id/ordering pairs to make the order lookup O(1) if I had a lot of these to do.  Note that you would also need to handle cases where your values are missing from the ordering -- I chose to move them to the end.

```
var order = new Dictionary<int,int>();
order.Add( 1, 1 );
order.Add( 2, 3 );
order.Add( 3, 2 );

var orderedFoos = foos.OrderBy( f => order.Contains(f.Id) ? order[f.Id] : int.MaxValue );
```

Comment: Performance isn't an issue here and values should match (exception is fine if they somehow do not) but thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a nested query, but it is quite inefficient with `O(n²)`.

```
var result = order.Select(o => foos.Single(f => f.Id == o));
```

If 'order' may contain ids not present in 'foos', you should use `SingleOrDefault()`. If `foos` might contain duplicate ids, you should use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`.

```
var result = order
    .Select(o => foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == o))
    .Select(f => f != null);
```

Maybe even a join will work, but I am not sure if it preserves the order.

```
var result = Enumerable.Join(order, foos, o => o, f => f.Id, (o, f) => f);
```

As Jon mentioned, the join will only work correctly if the input is well formed in the same way as required by my first suggestion.

Comment: Joins do preserve order in LINQ to Objects... but you could end up with duplicate or missing rows.

Comment: "var result = order.Select(o => foos.Single(f => f.Id == o));" this is what Mehrdid posted at start (and deleted). Actually - it's a valid approach in this case because performance is not an issue here at all. Anyway - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var order = new[] { 1, 3, 2 };
var foos = new[] { new Foo { Id = 1 }, new Foo { Id = 2 }, new Foo { Id = 3 } };

var query = from o in order
            join foo in foos on o equals foo.Id
            select foo;

var foos2 = query.ToArray();
```