# why doesnt' nhibernate support this "exists in list" syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i have the following query and its failing in Nhibernate 3 LINQ witha a "Non supported" exception.  Its [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986582/linq-to-nhibernate-get-by-array-of-ids-query) but this question was asked over a year ago so i am positive that the answer is out of date.

My DB tables are:

1. VacationRequest (id, personId)
2. VacationRequestDate (id, vacationRequestId)
3. Person (id, FirstName, LastName)

My Entities are:

1. VacationRequest (Person, IList)
2. VacationRequestDate (VacationRequest, Date)

Here is the query that is getting a "Non supported" Exception

```
 Session.Query<VacationRequestDate>()
   .Where(r => people
     .Contains(r.VacationRequest.Person, new PersonComparer()))
   .Fetch(r=>r.VacationRequest)
   .ToList();
```

is there a better way to write this that would be supported in Nhibernate?

fyi . .the PersonComparer just compared person.Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate does not understand the `PersonComparer` type, and thus cannot translate its usage to SQL.

Have you tried using the overload of `Contains` which does not accept a comparer? NHibernate should infer that you are comparing entity instances and properly use the ID in the SQL comparison (what else could it use?):

```
Session.Query<VacationRequestDate>()
    .Where(r => people.Contains(r.VacationRequest.Person))
    .Fetch(r => r.VacationRequest)
    .ToList();
```

Also, keep in mind that within a single NHibernate session, the same entity instance is always returned for the same ID. This means that `person1 == person1` should always be true if both `Person` instances were retrieved from the same session. This carries through relationships as well, so `vacationRequest1.Person == vacationRequest2.Person` will also be true within the same session if both vacation requests have the same person ID.

This means you can probably get rid of `PersonComparer` entirely unless you are mixing entities from multiple sessions through caching.

Answer (score 2):

nhibernate cannot translate your `new PersonComparer()` you should change it.

Comment: @ooo, if you see the expression tree in debug mode you can see it can't make this, but I think if you override equal member of your `Person` it can be done carefully. [but if you override it before for another purpose I suggest use hql]

Answer (score 0):

For starters it cant execute the code against that in your db.

Well here are my suggestions on how to go about this

```
var peopleIds= people.Select(x=>x.Id);
Session.Query<VacationRequestDate>()
    .Where(r => peopleIds.Contains(r.VacationRequest.PeopleId)).ToList()
    .Where(x=>people.Contains(r.VacationRequest,new         
     PersonComparer()).Select(r=>r.VacationRequest).ToList()
```

If you think this isnt wha tyou want to do then I would suggest you try your hand at Criteria queries or HQL and you can get exactly what you want from the db.

You can also use your comparer as follows. I like to make mine generic.
You can make it string comparison too and you will add your logic of ignore case etc here.

```
public class ComparerByIntId<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    where T : class, IIntegerIdentifiable
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now when you run your query it will be as follows:

```
Session.Query<VacationRequestDate>()
   .Where(r => people
   .Contains(r.VacationRequest.Person, new ComparerByIntId<Person>()))
   .Select(r=>r.VacationRequest)
   .ToList();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: `Where(r => peopleIds.Contains(r.VacationRequest.PeopleId)).ToList()` is not a good suggestion, load all data may be cause to crash also it's slow

Comment: How does it load all data? and we are in 21st century man.. what do you mean it will crash. say each person data is 1024 bytes large so the total space by say 1024 records returned is  1024*1024= 1mb of memory which i certainly think is manageable unless we are suddenly thinking about having mem constraints for 1mb.